# How to substruct dates in oracle db?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to substruct 2 dates(current date and hairdressing_date) to get the result from table to represent data during last 2 years.
I have following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT count(c_id) 
  INTO counter 
  FROM RESERVATIONS r
 WHERE r.customer_id = 1 
   AND (Sysdate - r.hairdressing_date) / 365 < 2;
```

It is custom, but I am not sure about '/ 365' part of code.

How to get the needed data correctly?
Could you write the correct implementation of this line?

Comment: Unfortunately this has been marked as a duplicate with a question so no new answers can be given, but the linked question isn’t in the context of a filter. You should know that it is good practice to not use functions against columns you are filtering on - it will mean that the expression needs to be evaluated for every row that matches the other filters, this requires work and means simple indexes will not be used (and also the optimizer will have a hard time estimating cardinality). In this case: where `r.hairdressing_date > add_months(sysdate,-24)` Is probably what you really want

Answer (score 2):

Please use `MONTHS_BETWEEN()` function like this:

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE), TO_DATE('22.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))/12 
  FROM DUAL;
```

and revert to this one considering your case:

```
SELECT count(c_id) 
  INTO counter 
  FROM RESERVATIONS r     
 WHERE r.customer_id = 1 
   AND MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE), hairdressing_date)/12 < 2;
```

Comment: What does mean FROM DUAL? How should I do comparison "> 2" ?

Comment: `SELECT count(c_id) INTO counter FROM RESERVATIONS r
    WHERE r.customer_id = 1 AND MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE), hairdressing_date)/12 < 2;`

Comment: Thank you for help

Comment: @andrew17 Please mark an answer as accepted